# Create Banner Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, mvvmcross

I am having a problem with PushNotifications. I am dealing when I get a notification whether the App is open or not. but when the App is open I want to display a banner just like the push notification but I do not know how, any tips?

I'm using MVVMCROSS 5.3 in Visual Studio for Mac 7.2

```
    public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        if (userInfo != null)
        {
            ProcessNotification(userInfo, false, application);
        }
    }
    ...

    public void ProcessNotification(NSDictionary options, bool fromFinishedLaunching, UIApplication application)
    {
        //Verificando se o App está e, primeiro plano para criar a notificação
        if (!fromFinishedLaunching)
        {
            // Check to see if the dictionary has the aps key.  This is the notification payload you would have sent
            if (null != options && options.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
            {
                //Get the aps dictionary
                NSDictionary aps = options.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

                NSDictionary alertString = new NSDictionary();
                string paramString = string.Empty;
                string body = string.Empty;
                string title = string.Empty;

                if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
                {
                    //Taking values ​​to create the banner
                    alertString = aps.ObjectForKey(new NSString("alert")) as NSDictionary;
                    body = (alertString[new NSString("body")] as NSString).ToString();
                    title = (alertString[new NSString("title")] as NSString).ToString();

                    **//Creating a banner like PushNotification
                    //?
                    //?
                    //?**
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            string idOrder = (options[new NSString("idOrder")] as NSString).ToString();

            if (idOrder != null)
            {
                var orderService = Mvx.Resolve<IOrderService>();
                var order = orderService.searchOrder();

                if (order.Result.status == "E")
                {
                    //Show my View 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which is the minimum iOS version your app is targeting?

Comment: @nmilcoff version 9.0